# My annotation pins are hidden

Tags: swift

I was making some callout accessories in the annotation function, and suddenly my annotation pins was hidden? They are only hidden, cause if i tap a place where i know there is a annotation, the annotationview will come up. The worst part is, i can't just regret (Cmd+Z), cause my computer went down while the project was running. I can't figure out what i changed, that will hide the pins.

```html
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        return nil
    }

    let identifier = "MyCustomAnnotation"

    var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(identifier)
    if annotationView == nil {
        annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
        annotationView?.canShowCallout = true

    } else {

        annotationView!.annotation = annotation

    }

    let image = UIImage(named: "advance.png")
    let button = UIButton(type: .DetailDisclosure)
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)
    button.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
    annotationView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = button

    let detailImage = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50))
    detailImage.image = UIImage(data: fishimages!)
    annotationView?.leftCalloutAccessoryView = detailImage


    return annotationView
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to call `MKAnnotationView()` to allocate unqueued *pins*? Modern practice is to use `let annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)` which will always return a non-nil pin...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not hidden, but transparent!

When you allocate your `MKAnnotationView()` (in the leg where you cannot de-queue an existing one), you are not setting the view's `.image` - therefore it is a blank view, not a pin. Consider using

```
let annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
```

which will always return a non-nil pin.